# Cannot install MacPorts in Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, macports, osx-mountain-lion

I downloaded MacPorts-2.1.2-10.8-MountainLion.pkg, but the installation stopped at "Running package script"...the "Install time remaining" is always "Less than a minute"...what is the problem???

Comment: What version of Xcode do you have installed? I have not looked at what commands the MacPorts install script runs, but the is at least [one other report of issues w/the Xcode Command Line Utilities in Mountain Lion](http://serverfault.com/questions/411212/macports-selfupdate-error#answer-411607) causing issues w/MacPorts. Since MacPorts is dependent on these utilities, the install script may check for them. In the aforelinked answer, updating Xcode resolved the issue.

Comment: @morgant, the latest Xcode, 4.4